# Regex to capture groups in traceroute with Java8

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I am trying to parse traceroute results in Java8 using Regex.

I am using the below regex to identify the groups.

```
^(\\d*).*[AS(\\d*)]?\\s+([\\w+\\.]+)\\s+\\(([\\d+\\.]+)\\)[\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+ms]+
```

Some example lines that I need to parse are:

```
1  10.33.128.1 (10.33.128.1)  4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms  
6  * [AS3356] 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms  
 * 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms  
  61.182.180.62 (61.182.180.62) 175.300 ms  203.001 ms
```

And I want to extract the hop number (if available), ASN (if available), hostname, IP and time

but with the above regex, it matches the strings 1,2, and 4 which is what I want but only gives me hop, host and ASN.

My code is like this:

```
Pattern hop_pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "^(\\d*).*[AS(\\d*)]?\\s+([\\w+\\.]+)\\s+\\(([\\d+\\.]+)\\)[\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+ms]+")
Matcher m = hop_pattern.matcher(target);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("count: " + m.groupCount());
    for(int i = 1; i < m.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "->" + m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Some example lines that I need to parse are:

> 1  10.33.128.1 (10.33.128.1)  4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms
>   6  * [AS3356] 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms
>   * 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms
>       61.182.180.62 (61.182.180.62) 175.300 ms  203.001 ms

And I want to extract the hop number (if available), ASN (if available), hostname, IP and time

but with the above regex, it matches the strings 1,2, and 4 which is what I want but only gives me hop, host and ASN.

My code is like this:

```
    Pattern hop_pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "^(\\d*).*[AS(\\d*)]?\\s+([\\w+\\.]+)\\s+\\(([\\d+\\.]+)\\)[\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+ms]+")
    Matcher m = hop_pattern.matcher(target);

    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("count: " + m.groupCount());
        for(int i = 1; i < m.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "->" + m.group(i));
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if something is wrong with the code or the regex itself. Thanks for help!

Update: Some examples and sample output

> 1  [AS0] 10.200.200.200 (10.200.200.200)  37.526 ms  35.793 ms  37.728 ms
>   Expected Output:
>   hop: 1
>   asn: 0
>   hostname: 10.200.200.200
>   ip: 10.200.200.200
>   time: [37.526, 35.793, 37.728]
>
> 2  [AS0] scsc-usr-13500-02-eth1-07.xyz.com (10.96.15.3)  37.927 ms  36.122 ms *
>   Expected Output:
>   hop: 2
>   asn: 0
>   hostname: scsc-usr-13500-02-eth1-07.xyz.com
>   ip: 10.96.15.3
>   time: [37.927, 36.122]

I am not sure if something is wrong with the code or the regex itself. Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you expect the complete line to be printed to console. The complete line is a match but you cycle through the groups instead of printing the complete line.

Comment: Can you put add a sample of your expected extraction for that example?

Comment: @Ankur a problem that jumps out right away is that you didn't escape `[` and `]` in your regex.  Also, `.*` before the [AS...] match will gobble up the [AS...] part as well since `*` is greedy.  But to give you a complete answer, we need to know exactly what your desired output is.

Comment: Thank you @Misha. Your input helped me understand the issue with my regex.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

### Part 1

In order to capture everything you're looking for, you need to use two separate regular expressions. The reason for this is regex will only capture the **last** group it finds that matches the criteria and you have multiple *times* in your traceroute results (e.g. `4.452 ms`, `3.459 ms`, and `3.474 ms` in your first line).

For the sake of understanding which groups are being captured, you can use the following regex (it is PCRE and won't work in Java, but it gives you a clear indication of which group is being captured).

[This code can be seen in use here](https://regex101.com/r/FROygz/1)

```
^(?P<hop>\d+)?[\h*]*(?:\[AS(?<ASN>\d*)\])?\h+(?<hostname>[\w\.]+)\h+\((?<ip>[\d+\.]+)\)\h+(?<times>.*?)\h*$
```

With a slight modification, the above regex can be used in Java (horizontal whitespace `\h` and named capture groups `(?<name>...)` are not supported in Java regex as far as I'm aware).

[This code can be seen in use here](https://regex101.com/r/FROygz/2)

```
^(\d+)?[\ \t*]*(?:\[AS(\d*)\])?[\ \t]+([\w\.]+)[\ \t]+\(([\d+\.]+)\)[\ \t]+(.*?)[\ \t]*$
```

**Note**: Both global `g` and multi-line `m` modifiers are used.

---

### Part 2

Run this second regular expression on the *times* you capture in **Part 1** to gather a list of all the times.

[This code can be seen in user here](https://regex101.com/r/YshuRQ/2)

```
([\d.]+)
```

---

---

## Results

### Part 1

#### Input

```
1  10.33.128.1 (10.33.128.1)  4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms  
6  * [AS3356] 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms  
 * 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms  
  61.182.180.62 (61.182.180.62) 175.300 ms  203.001 ms
```

#### Output

**Match 1**

- Full match   0-60    `1  10.33.128.1 (10.33.128.1)  4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms`
- Group 1. `1`
- Group 3. `10.33.128.1`
- Group 4. `10.33.128.1`
- Group 5. `4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms`

**Match 2**

- Full match   61-124  `6  * [AS3356] 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms`
- Group 1. `6`
- Group 2.`3356`
- Group 3. `4.68.72.218`
- Group 4. `4.68.72.218`
- Group 5. `12.432 ms  11.819 ms`

**Match 3**

- Full match   125-177 `* 4.68.72.218 (4.68.72.218)  12.432 ms  11.819 ms`
- Group 3. `4.68.72.218`
- Group 4. `4.68.72.218`
- Group 5. `12.432 ms  11.819 ms`

**Match 4**

- Full match   178-232 `61.182.180.62 (61.182.180.62) 175.300 ms  203.001 ms`
- Group 3. `61.182.180.62`
- Group 4. `61.182.180.62`
- Group 5. `175.300 ms  203.001 ms`

---

### Part 2

#### Input

```
4.452 ms  3.459 ms  3.474 ms
```

#### Output

**Match 1**

- Full match   0-5 `4.452`
- Group 1. `4.452`

**Match 2**

- Full match   10-15   `3.459`
- Group 1. `3.459`

**Match 3**

- Full match   20-25   `3.474`
- Group 1. `3.474`

---

---

## Edits

Thank you to [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) for pointing out that Java does indeed allow named capture groups as other regex flavors do.

Here's an updated regex since Java does support named capture groups `(?<name>...)`

[This regex can be seen in use here](https://regex101.com/r/FROygz/3)

```
^(?P<hop>\d+)?[\t *]*(?:\[AS(?<ASN>\d*)\])?[\t ]+(?<hostname>[\w\.]+)[\t ]+\((?<ip>[\d+\.]+)\)[\t ]+(?<times>.*?)[\t ]*$
```

Comment: Named captures are available in Java too.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you, I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much @ctwheels. I got it working in Java with some small changes. Here is the expressing I used  `Pattern hop_pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "^(?<hop>\\d+)?[\\W]+(?:\\[AS(?<asn>\\d*)\\])?[\\s]+(?<hostname>[\\S\\.]+)[\\s]+\\((?<ip>[\\d+\\.]+)\\)[\\s]+(?<times>.*?)[\\s]*$");`

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar solution in preparation, but tried to catch everything at once.

It works now as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/FROygz/6).

`^(?P<hop>\d+)?[\W]*(?:\[AS(?<ASN>\d*)\])?[\t ]+(?<hostname>[\w\.]+)[\t ]+\((?<ip>[\d+\.]+)\)[\t ]+(?<times>(?:(?:[\t ]*(\d+\.\d+)\sms)\s*(?:(\d+\.\d+)\sms[\t ]*)(?:(\d+\.\d+)\sms[\t ]+)?))[\t ]*$`

*Update:* Since \h does not exist in Java, I replaced \h with [\t ], expect for one instance where I preferred \W.
*Addendum*: As noted by @Holger, \h *is* available in Java 8.

However, it's most probably still easier to process the times in an extra step as shown in @ctwheels excellent answer.

Comment: `\h` doesn't exist in Java, you have to find a workaround to mimick it. Also you don't need to escape the dot inside a character class. You can make more tests for Java regex with this site: http://www.regexplanet.com

Comment: Thank you @Casimir et Hippolyte. That was a hard one, but fun.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: From the [documentation of `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef): `\h A horizontal whitespace character: [ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`

Comment: @Holger: you are right, it has been added in Java 8, but isn't available in previous versions.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: well, this question has been tagged with `[java-8]`…